# How to query string lengths with clGetPlatformInfo (and friends)?

Tags: c, malloc, opencl

**Short version: Is there an official/correct way to query for the size of strings like `CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR`?**

**Long version:**
Looking at OpenCL functions like [clGetPlatformInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformInfo.html) I want to find out how much space to allocate for the result.  The function has this signature:

```
cl_int clGetPlatformInfo(cl_platform_id platform,
    cl_platform_info param_name,
    size_t param_value_size,
    void *param_value,
    size_t *param_value_size_ret)
```

The docs say:

```
param_value_size

Specifies the size in bytes of memory pointed to by
param_value. This size in bytes must be greater
than or equal to size of return type specified in the
table below.
```

All of the return types are listed as `char[]`.  I wanted to know how much space to reserve so I called it like this, where I pass `0` for `param_value_size` and `NULL` for `param_value`, hoping to get the correct size return in `param_value_size_ret`:

```
  size_t size = 0;
  l_success = clGetPlatformInfo(platform_id,
                                CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, 0, NULL, &size);

  if( l_success != CL_SUCCESS)
  {
    printf("Failed getting vendor name size.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("l_success = %d, size = %d\n", l_success, size);
  char* vendor = NULL;
  vendor = malloc(size);
  if( vendor )
  {
    l_success = clGetPlatformInfo(platform_id,
                                  CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, size, vendor, &size);
    if( l_success != CL_SUCCESS )
    {
      printf("Failed getting vendor name.\n");
      return -1;
    }
    printf("Vendor name is '%s', length is %d\n", vendor, strlen(vendor));
  } else {
    printf("malloc failed.\n");
    return -1;
  }
```

It behaved as I had hoped, it return a size of 19 for the string, "NVIDIA Corporation" (size included null terminator) and `strlen` return 18.  Is this the "right" way to query for parameter size or am I just getting lucky with my vendor's implementation?  Has anyone seen this idiom fail on some vendor?

**Edit:** The bit that is tripping me up is this, "This size in bytes must be greater than or equal to size of return type", it seems like when I pass `0` and `NULL` the call should fail because that's not greater than or equal to the size of the returned **value**.  I'm not sure why they say "return type".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it *is*  the right way.

In the [same doc you've mentioned](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformInfo.html):

> If `param_value` is NULL, it is ignored.

And below:

> Returns `CL_SUCCESS` if the function is executed successfully. Otherwise, it returns the following:
>
> ...
>
> `CL_INVALID_VALUE` if `param_name` is not one of the supported values or if size in bytes specified by `param_value_size` is less than size of return type and `param_value` is not a NULL value.

So even if it is not stated explicitly, if `param_value` is NULL no error should be produced, so the code is supposed to work properly.

Here is a piece of code from [Khronos OpenCL C++ bindings](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.1/cl.hpp) ([specs](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.1.pdf)). They too do it this way, and I think it counts as "official":

```
// Specialized GetInfoHelper for STRING_CLASS params
template <typename Func>
struct GetInfoHelper<Func, STRING_CLASS>
{
    static cl_int get(Func f, cl_uint name, STRING_CLASS* param)
    {
        ::size_t required;
        cl_int err = f(name, 0, NULL, &required);
        if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
            return err;
        }

        char* value = (char*) alloca(required);
        err = f(name, required, value, NULL);
        if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
            return err;
        }

        *param = value;
        return CL_SUCCESS;
    }
};
```

Comment: Great answer!  Much appreciated.  And I think drawing on the Khronos example helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note in the example that while asking for the value, the forth parameter has to be NULL. Otherwise some platforms answer a CL_INVALID_VALUE as return.

As the upfront query and malloc is somehow over the top, I use one large char buffer as workaround.

```
char vendor[10240];
l_success = clGetPlatformInfo( platform_id,
                     CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, sizeof(vendor), vendor, NULL);
```